# Laravel/Spatie Roles and Permission issue: How to change default model

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

Is there any way to work with Spatie roles and permission by indicating different model name not like using user model in Laravel 8?

Comment: which model  do you want to change ?

Comment: I wanna change default User model and want to use Person Model instead of User model

Comment: as per my understanding changing user model is nothing to do with this package.so you can ref below answer and add HasRole trait ,ref:https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/basic-usage/basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `app/config/auth.php` file and change the followings with your own auth table and model name:

```php
'table' => 'custom_auth_table'
'model' => 'CustomAuthModel',
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the default model of this package yesterday and hope this will help you.

I will outline a few steps you need to modified after you installed laravel spatie permission package:

Example new default model: Customer (or whichever you want).

1. You need to create your new model `Customer.php` in `App\Models\`.
2. Don't forget to add `use HasRoles` inside the class and `use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;` at the top of `Customer.php` file.
3. Go to `config\auth.php` change `providers` to `customer` according to the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snvKaNj4Byc&t=3s&ab_channel=MSCoding)
4. Database: You also need to change the value of `model_type` column to
   `App\Models\Customer` in both `model_has_permission` & `model_has_role` table.

Extra: if you already have a existed table and wish to generate model file from it.
You can go to use [laracademygenerators](https://github.com/laracademy/generators) package.